# View data from two Modal in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to view the data from two or more Modal and  view the that data just three data with descending to front-end ?

i was try with this code but not success..

```
class FrontController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
        {
            $lowongans = Lowongan::orderBy('id', 'desc');
            $agendas = Agenda::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->take(3)
                ->get();
            return view('index', compact('lowongans','agendas'));
        }}
```

in the index.blade i try to access the data

```
<div class="post-row1">
  @foreach($agendas as $agenda)
    {{$agenda->name}}
  @endforeach
</div>
<div class="post-row2">
  @foreach($lowongans as $lowongan)
    {{$lowongan->name}}
  @endforeach
</div>
```

its not success, just Agenda:: can access but not with the Lowongan::

Comment: I asume you mean "Model"? One can not really see why you cant access Agenda with the provided code, an error msg would be nice.
My guess is you forgot the namespace like "use App\Model\Lowongan".

Comment: use dd($lowongans) to print the variable.

Comment: As @Thomas pointed out, you didn't call a fetch method on your model. You need one to finish it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `get()`.

```
$lowongans = Lowongan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Laravel only prepares the query until you actually call methods like `get`, `first`, etc.

Comment: Yes, i know but i want call two modals no one